# Vim mapping does not respect autoindenting

Tags: vim

I'm trying to learn vimscript, so I cannot use plugins. What I'm trying to do is auto wrapping HTML tags in '<>' and auto closing them, like this.

User types

> html>

As soon as he hits the '>', it maps to this.

`<html>
   [cursor]
</html>`

I managed to do this with the following vimrc

```
set filetype on
set incsearch
set scrolloff=5
set wildmode=longest,list,full
set tabstop=4
set autoindent
set cindent
set number
nnoremap <leader> ddp 
noremap _ ddkP
nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
nnoremap jk <esc>
nnoremap <esc> <nop>
let mapleader = "-" 
let localleader = "\\"
autocmd FileType html set tabstop=2
autocmd FileType html set autoindent
autocmd FileType html inoremap <buffer> > <esc>vbyi<<esc>lea><enter><enter></<esc>pa><esc>ki<tab>
```

But, when I do this with a second tag, it respects only the first indenting, so it goes

`<html>
     <head>
     <title>
     </title>
     </head>
</html>`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No indentation is added if the line is already created.

Try

```
autocmd FileType html <buffer> > inoremap <Esc>vbyi<<Esc>lea><CR></<Esc>pa><Esc>O<Tab>
```

With this, an empty line between tags is creaetd AFTER the closing tag.

Comment: This leaves an error in .vimrc:
`Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "html":
E488: Trailing characters: <buffer> > inoremap <Esc>vbyi<<Esc>lea><CR></<Esc>p
a><Esc>O<Tab>`
When I remove `<buffer>` and put `>` after `inoremap`, it doesn't add a new line.

Comment: Well, turns out I had a typo. Your solution worked, mister. Thank you very much.